# Understanding Groovy count closures

Tags: groovy, closures

I just started working with Groovy and, while it's refreshing to finally have closures to work with in a Java environment, I'm having problems getting `count` to work like I want.

Let's say I have a class `Foo` that looks something like this:

```
public class Foo {

    private boolean isBar;

    public boolean isBar() {
        return isBar;
    }

    public boolean setIsBar(boolean isBar) {
        this.isBar = isBar;
    }

}
```

Now let's say I have a `List` of `Foo` instances, and I want to count the number of `Foo` objects where `isBar` is true. I was expecting it to look something like this:

```
foos.count { it.isBar() }
```

Or using the property notation, simply:

```
foos.count { it.bar }
```

However, this does not return the expected results, it just returns 0.

I tried testing this with a simple `List` of ints. To count the occurrences of 2, I could just do:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3].count(2)
```

But shouldn't I be able to do the following using a closure?

```
[1, 2, 2, 3].count { it == 2 }
```

The latter doesn't seem to return the expected results either. The research that I've done seems to indicate that what I'm doing is correct, but clearly it's not. What is the correct way to use this?

Comment: works for me, using groovy 1.8.4

Comment: Granted, I'm using 1.6.0 since it's an older project, but I would be surprised if upgrading to 1.8 was the difference.

Comment: You should make your `Foo` class more *groovyish*. `class Foo { boolean bar }` (Hard to make it look good in a comment...). Setters/getters are automatically there for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Groovy JDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#count%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) `Collection#count(Closure)` wasn't added until 1.8.0. You could try `#sum` instead:

```
assert [1, 2, 2, 3].sum() { it == 2? 1 : 0 } == 2
```

Comment: Thanks Justin -- can't believe I missed that in the docs. I will try upgrading to 1.8.

Comment: @Tyler If you have problems, try upgrading to version 1.7 first, then from there to 1.8. Despite the version numbering, each upgrade needs lots of niggly little code tweaks.

Answer (score 2):

The docs for `Collection.count` under 1.6:

> `Number   count(Object value)`
>
> Counts the number of occurrences of the given value inside this collection

Thus:

```
> [1, 2, 2, 3].count(2)
2
```

The docs for `Collection.count` under 1.8:

> `Number   count(Object value)`
>
> Counts the number of occurrences of the given value inside this collection.
>
> `Number   count(Closure closure)`
>
> Counts the number of occurrences which satisfy the given closure from inside this collection.

The docs really, really help.

Answer (score 1):

In groovy 1.8+ you can write:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3].iterator().count { it == 2 }
```

Due backward compatibility, new method signature of DefaultGroovyMethods is:

```
public static Number count(Iterator self, Closure closure) {
```

Comment: the round braces after count are optional. if used then they would enclose the curly clamps enclosed iterator execution block.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr are u talking about { bracket? Could you write the result code?

Comment: [1, 2, 2, 3].iterator().count( { it == 2 } )